# How can I filter objects selected w/ jq based on other values?

Tags: json, linux, shell, sh, jq

I'm trying to get hold of one of the field values depending on another field's value.

```
{  
   "dirty": "false",
   "instances": {  
      "random-generated-id-1": {  
         "state": "ON",
         "id": "random-generated-id-1"
      },
      "random-generated-id-2": {
         "state": "OFF",
         "id": "random-generated-id-2"
      }
   }
}
```

I want to get `id` of the instance which is in `ON` state.

`jq ".instances"` gives me both the instances. How do I get only `random-generated-id-1`?

Answer (score 4):

```
jq -r '.instances[] | select(.state=="ON") | .id'
```